# Linq to xml - how do i create this using LINQ in C#

Tags: xml, linq

how do i create this using linq to XML in C#

```
  <User xmlns="user">
```

Comment: Did you try Googling `linq xml xmlns`?

Comment: XElement user = XElement.Parse("<User xmlns=\"user\"/>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard solution relies on the implicit casts defined by LINQ-to-XML. Just declare your namespace, and then concatenate it with a string name.

For example:

```cs
// implicit conversion from string to XNamespace
XNamespace xmlns = "user";

// implicit conversion from XNamespace and string to XName
XElement user =
    new XElement(xmlns + "User");

Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
// returns: <User xmlns="user"/>
```